# My ubuntu 22.04 is showing blank screen in 2024 not showing any screen after power on

Tags: 22.04

My ubuntu 22.04 os is blank screen which means nothing showing up to me after power on of my laptop in 2024. I have Acer Nitro 5 AMD Radeon laptop. There is no solution find working in community to solve this black screen problem in Feb 7, 2024.

Comment: Did this problem occur before upgrading too? You could select advance options in GRUB and boot to a previous kernel

Comment: Can anybody in ubuntu community can give the solution for this problem?

Comment: No,this problem did not occur before, there is no button working to enter into Grub , Actually I am using this ubuntu 22.04 from last 2 years in my window 10 acer laptop by first boot into 22.04.This time anything is not working or not showing any screen after power on my laptop, pls give me solution urgently, if any have in the community

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/1004020 for how to enter GRUB. At the same time, you can try the `nomodeset` kernel command line parameter to see if disabling the GPU drivers will fix the blank screen problem. If literally "anything is not working or not showing any screen after power", then we can't help you. Your computer needs to at least be able to boot into BIOS or something. If it can't then it's a hardware problem and your computer needs to be repaired

Comment: There is no bootable screen showing to me while switch on power button, so how can I go to GRUB and boot problem in my case.

Comment: Is there a screen with your manufacturer's logo? If not, take your computer to the computer repair shop

Comment: Ok, I will go to repair shop.